# CLASSIC ASP PAGINATION

Tags: asp-classic, pagination

I use this code to show pagination of recordset in classic asp + Mysql:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <% IF Cint(PageNo) > 1 then %>
    <li><a rel="1" href="#" data-topic="<%=Request.QueryString("TOPIC_ID")%>" data-page="1">Prime</a></li>
    <li><a rel="<%=PageNo-1%>" href="#" data-topic="<%=Request.QueryString("TOPIC_ID")%>" data-page="<%=PageNo-1%>"><</a></li>
    <% End IF%>
    <% For intID=1 To TotalPage%>
    <% if intID=Cint(PageNo) Then%>
    <li><a href="" class="selected"><%=intID%></a></li>
    <%Else%>
    <li><a rel="<%=intID%>" href="#" data-topic="<%=Request.QueryString("TOPIC_ID")%>" data-page="<%=intID%>"><%=intID%></a></li>
    <%End IF%>
    <%Next%>
    <% IF Cint(PageNo) < TotalPage Then %>
    <li><a rel="<%=PageNo+1%>" href="#" data-topic="<%=Request.QueryString("TOPIC_ID")%>" data-page="<%=PageNo+1%>">></a></li>
    <li><a rel="<%=TotalPage%>" href="#" data-topic="<%=Request.QueryString("TOPIC_ID")%>" data-page="<%=TotalPage%>">Ultime</a></li>
    <% End IF%>
  </ul>
```

But If I have a lot of pageresults, it show a long line of number.... How could show only 5 page an when change page, show next?

like so:

first < 1 2 3 4 5 > last

and if I click on 5

first < 5 6 7 8 9 > last

etc...

Answer (score 1):

This code works also if you want to keep some other querystring parameters. It removes the page value, adds the new page value and builds the paging control html.

It uses the Twitter Bootstrap Styles: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#pagination

Usage:

```
Response.Write PagingControl(10, 30, "?field-keywords=whatever&page=7")
```

Code:

```
    Public Function RemoveEmptyQueryStringParameters(strQueryString)
        If IsNullOrEmpty(strQueryString) Then Exit Function

        Dim strNewQueryString: strNewQueryString = ""
        strQueryString = Replace(strQueryString, "&amp;", "&")
        strQueryString = Replace(strQueryString, "?", "&")

        Dim arrQueryString: arrQueryString = Split(strQueryString ,"&")

        For i=0 To UBound(arrQueryString)
            strTempParameter = Left( arrQueryString(i), Instr( arrQueryString(i) & "=", "=" ) - 1 )
            strTempParameterValue = Right( arrQueryString(i), Len( arrQueryString(i) ) - InstrRev( arrQueryString(i), "=" ) )
            If Not IsNullOrEmpty(strTempParameterValue) Then
               strNewQueryString = strNewQueryString & "&" & arrQueryString(i)
            End If
        Next

        If InStr(strNewQueryString,"&") = 1 Then
            strNewQueryString = "?" & Right(strNewQueryString, Len(strNewQueryString) - 1)
        End If
        strNewQueryString = Replace(strNewQueryString, "&", "&amp;")

        Erase arrQueryString
        Set arrQueryString = Nothing

        RemoveEmptyQueryStringParameters = Trim(strNewQueryString)
    End Function

    Public Function AddQueryStringParameter(ByVal strQueryString, ByVal strParameter, ByVal strValue)
        Dim strNewQueryString: strNewQueryString = ""
        strNewQueryString = Replace(strQueryString, "&amp;", "&")
        strNewQueryString = Replace(strNewQueryString, "?", "&")

        strNewQueryString = strNewQueryString & "&" & strParameter & "=" & strValue

        If InStr(strNewQueryString,"&") = 1 Then
            strNewQueryString = "?" & Right(strNewQueryString, Len(strNewQueryString) - 1)
        End If
        strNewQueryString = Replace(strNewQueryString, "&", "&amp;")

        AddQueryStringParameter = Trim(strNewQueryString)
    End Function

    Public Function PagingControl(ByVal intPage, ByVal intPageCount, ByVal strQueryString)
        If intPageCount <= 1 Then
            PagingControl = ""
            Exit Function
        End If

        strQueryString = RemoveEmptyQueryStringParameters(strQueryString)
        strQueryString = RemoveQueryStringParameter(strQueryString, "page")

        Dim strQueryStringPaging: strQueryStringPaging = ""
      Dim strHtml: strHtml = "<div class=""pagination""><ul>"

      If cInt(intPage) > 1 Then
             strQueryStringPaging = AddQueryStringParameter(strQueryString, "page", "1")
             strHtml = strHtml & "<li><a href=""" & strWebSiteUrl & strQueryStringPaging & """>Anfang</a></li>"

             strQueryStringPaging = AddQueryStringParameter(strQueryString, "page", CInt(intPage - 1))
         strHtml = strHtml & "<li><a href=""" & strWebSiteUrl & strQueryStringPaging & """>&lt; Zur&uuml;ck</a></li>"
      Else
        strHtml = strHtml & "<li class=""disabled""><a href=""#"">Anfang</a></li>" & _
        "<li class=""disabled""><a href=""#"">&lt; Zur&uuml;ck</a></li>"
      End If

        Dim intPagesToShow: intPagesToShow = 10

      If intPageCount >= intPagesToShow Then
         If Cint(intPage)>Int(intPagesToShow/2) Then
            If Cint(intPage)>(intPageCount-Int(intPagesToShow/2)) Then
                        intStart = intPageCount-intPagesToShow
                        intEnd = intPageCount
            Else
                        intStart = intPage-Int(intPagesToShow/2)
                        intEnd = intPage+Int(intPagesToShow/2)
            End If
         Else
            intStart = 1
            intEnd = intPagesToShow
         End If
      Else
         intStart=1
         intEnd=intPageCount
      End If

      If intStart=0 Then
         intStart=1
      End If

      For i = intStart To intEnd
          If Cint(intPage)=i Then
             strHtml = strHtml & "<li class=""active""><a href=""" & strWebSiteUrl & strQueryStringPaging & """>" & i & "</a></li>"
          Else
             strQueryStringPaging = AddQueryStringParameter(strQueryString, "page", Cint(i))
             strHtml = strHtml & "<li><a href=""" & strWebSiteUrl & strQueryStringPaging & """>" & i & "</a></li>"
          End If
      Next

      If cInt(intPage) < cInt(intPageCount) Then
         strQueryStringPaging = AddQueryStringParameter(strQueryString, "page", CInt(intPage + 1))
         strHtml = strHtml & "<li><a href=""" & strWebSiteUrl & strQueryStringPaging & """>Vorw&auml;rts &gt;</a></li>"

            strQueryStringPaging = AddQueryStringParameter(strQueryString, "page", Cint(intPageCount))
            strHtml = strHtml & "<li><a href=""" & strWebSiteUrl & strQueryStringPaging & """>Ende</a></li>"
      Else
         strHtml = strHtml & "<li class=""disabled""><a href=""#"">Vorw&auml;rts &gt;</a></li>" & _
         "<li class=""disabled end""><a href=""#"">Ende</a></li>"
      End If

      strHtml = strHtml & "</ul></div>"

      PagingControl = Trim(strHtml)
    End Function
```

Comment: This example code has too many dependant functions missing to be truly useful.

Answer (score 1):

I needed a simular solution in ASP. 
I could not find anything usefull, so I made something myself.

I normally only program in PHP, but that wasn't possible in the case where I made this.
So if my code is a bit slopy, feel free to improve ;)

A little function I cooked up:

```
<%

page = cInt(Request.QueryString("pg"))
pages = cInt(number of pages)

if page <1 then page = 1
if page > pages then page = pages

Function paginationHTML(page, lastPage, URL)

if page >1 then
    paginationHTML = "<a href=""" & URL & page-1 & """>prev</a>"
    paginationHTML = paginationHTML & "<a href=""" & URL & "1"">1</a>"
end if

if page >2 then
    paginationHTML = paginationHTML & "<a>...</a>"
end if

if page >0 then
    paginationHTML = paginationHTML & "<a href=""" & URL & page & """ class='jp-current'>"& page &"</a>"
end if

if lastPage >2 then
    if page < lastPage-1 then
        paginationHTML = paginationHTML & "<a>...</a>"
    end if
end if

if page < lastPage then
    paginationHTML = paginationHTML & "<a href=""" & URL & lastPage & """>"&lastPage&"</a>"
    paginationHTML = paginationHTML & "<a href=""" & URL & page+1 & """>next</a>"
end if


End Function

%>
```

use like so:

```
<%=paginationHTML(page,pages,"?pg=")%>
```

Comment: @johnathan-joosten - How do i use this code so that the paging starts a 1 .. at the moment, paging starts at 0? .. Cheers

Comment: I changed the code so it doesn't show a page 0.
It only should have given page 0 if there were no pages. 
Hope this small improvement helps you.