# Classic ASP - Displaying page numbers in pagination

Tags: asp-classic

Im a very very newbie at ASP, but im trying to work out pagination.

So far im displaying 10 images per page and then just displaying the 'prev' and 'next' links at the bottom of the page which works perfect.

But i would like to display the amount of pages in between the prev and next links .. i cant seem to get anything working.

What i have so far is as follows, if someone could help out i would be very grateful.

```vb
    Dim page
    pageSize = 10
    page = Request("page")
    if len(page) = 0 then page = 0
    if not(isNumeric(page)) then page = 0

    'Enter pagination for loop
    start = page * pageSize
    finish = start + pageSize - 1

    for current = start to finish
        if current < ubound(arrMultiImages) then
            Response.Write "<img src='" & arrMultiImages(current,1) & "'><br />" & vbCrLf
        end if
    next

    if start > 0 then response.write "<a href=""" & urlPage & "?page=" & page - 1 & """>Prev</a><br>"
    if finish < ubound(arrMultiImages) then response.write "<a href=""" & urlPage & "?page=" & page + 1 & """>Next</a>"
```

Comment: Total pages is `Ceil(TotalRecords/pageSize)`

Comment: totalRecords = ubound(arrMultiImages)
Response.Write (Int(totalRecords/pageSize))

Comment: Yes, that should work. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Im looking for some code to display the page numbers i.e  prev 2 3 4 next kind of thing

Comment: possible duplicate of [CLASSIC ASP PAGINATION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896483/classic-asp-pagination)

Comment: I hope the above link helps

Comment: Thanks for that, but im getting errors trying to run that code

Comment: What errors are you getting?